# Camel route over Mina2-Endpoint with option transferExchange=true

Tags: apache-camel, apache-karaf, apache-servicemix, apache-mina

```
<route id="loadbalancer">
    <from uri="{{direct.loadbalancer}}"/>
    <loadBalance>
        <failover roundRobin="true"/>
        <to uri="mina2:tcp://localhost:9981?sync=false&amp;transferExchange=true"/>
        <to uri="{{mina.server2}}"/>
        <to uri="{{mina.server3}}"/>
        <to uri="{{mina.server4}}"/>
    </loadBalance>
</route>

<route id="decoupler">
        <from uri="mina2:tcp://localhost:9981?sync=false&amp;transferExchange=true"/>
        <to uri="{{direct.vm.processSOAP}}" />
    </route>
```

Background: I want to loadbalance the incoming exchanges and send them to mina2-Endpoints. In the second route I just want to decouple them to another context. The two routes are in two different camelContexts. The project build with maven is succesfull, also the deploying to the Apache Service Mix Karaf. When I try to send an exchange (body type is String) to the mina2-endpoint without the option transferExchange=true, it works fine, but my header values I set before are gone. That's why I have to use transferExchange_true. But when I try now sending an exchange, I get an Error on the mina2-endpoint. The log-message from Karaf is shown below:

> 2014-11-14 13:10:56,440 | WARN  | ool-134-thread-1 | Mina2Consumer                    | ?                                   ? | 195 - org.apache.camel.camel-mina2 - 2.13.
>   2 | Closing session as an exception was thrown from MINA
>   2014-11-14 13:10:56,440 | WARN  | ool-134-thread-1 | DefaultIoFilterChain             | ?                                   ? | 33 - org.apache.mina.core - 2.0.7 | Unexpe
>   cted exception from exceptionCaught handler.
>   org.apache.camel.CamelException: org.apache.mina.filter.codec.ProtocolDecoderException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultExchangeHolder (Hex
>   dump: 79 3E 0D 0A 20 20 20 3C 2F 73 6F 61 70 65 6E 76 3A 48 65 61 64 65 72 3E 0D 0A 20 20 20 3C 73 6F 61 70 65 6E 76 3A 42 6F 64 79 20 77 73 75 3A 49 64 3D 22 63 34 34 62
>    31 65 66 38 2D 31 63 35 30 2D 34 62 38 65 2D 38 31 33 37 2D 38 30 62 35 38 30 35 33 61 37 33 30 22 20 78 6D 6C 6E 73 3A 77 73 75 3D 22 68 74 74 70 3A 2F 2F 64 6F 63 73 2
>   E 6F 61 73 69 73 2D 6F 70 65 6E 2E 6F 72 67 2F 77 73 73 2F 32 30 30 34 2F 30 31 2F 6F 61 73 69 73 2D 32 30 30 34 30 31 2D 77 73 73 2D 77 73 73 65 63 75 72 69 74 79 2D 75
>   74 69 6C 69 74 79 2D 31 2E 30 2E 78 73 64 22 3E 0D 0A 20 20 20 20 20 20 3C 6E 30 3A 47 65 74 56 65 68 69 63 6C 65 53 70 65 63 69 66 69 63 61 74 69 6F 6E 42 79 56 49 4E 20
>    78 6D 6C 6E 73 3A 6E 30 3D 22 68 74 74 70 3A 2F 2F 78 6D 6C 64 65 66 73 2E 76 6F 6C 6B 73 77 61 67 65 6E 61 67 2E 63 6F 6D 2F 43 53 50 2F 55 73 65 64 43 61 72 73 2F 56 6
>   5 68 69 63 6C 65 53 70 65 63 69 66 69 63 61 74 69 6F 6E 52 65 63 6F 76 65 72 79 53 65 72 76 69 63 65 2F 56 31 22 20 78 6D 6C 6E 73 3A 70 72 78 3D 22 75 72 6E 3A 73 61 70
>   2E 63 6F 6D 3A 70 72 6F 78 79 3A 46 35 50 3A 2F 31 53 41 49 2F 54 41 53 34 32 41 35 33 42 41 38 35 32 45 30 30 30 32 32 36 37 43 35 3A 37 30 31 3A 32 30 31 33 2F 30 35 2F
>    32 34 22 20 78 6D 6C 6E 73 3A 6E 31 3D 22 68 74 74 70 3A 2F 2F 78 6D 6C 64 65 66 73 2E 76 6F 6C 6B 73 77 61 67 65 6E 61 67 2E 63 6F 6D 2F 44 44 2F 56 65 68 69 63 6C 65 2
>   F 52 65 66 2F 56 31 22 20 78 6D 6C 6E 73 3A 73 6F 61 70 2D 65 6E 76 3D 22 68 74 74 70 3A 2F 2F 73 63 68 65 6D 61 73 2E 78 6D 6C 73 6F 61 70 2E 6F 72 67 2F 73 6F 61 70 2F
>   65 6E 76 65 6C 6F 70 65 2F 22 3E 0D 0A 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 3C 6E 31 3A 56 65 68 69 63 6C 65 52 65 66 3E 0D 0A 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 3C 6E 31 3A 56 49
>    4E 3E 57 41 55 5A 5A 5A 38 54 37 43 41 30 34 31 35 35 38 3C 2F 6E 31 3A 56 49 4E 3E 0D 0A 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 3C 2F 6E 31 3A 56 65 68 69 63 6C 65 52 65 66 3E 0D 0
>   A 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 3C 6E 30 3A 4C 61 6E 67 75 61 67 65 3E 64 65 3C 2F 6E 30 3A 4C 61 6E 67 75 61 67 65 3E 0D 0A 20 20 20 20 20 20 3C 2F 6E 30 3A 47 65 74 56 65
>   68 69 63 6C 65 53 70 65 63 69 66 69 63 61 74 69 6F 6E 42 79 56 49 4E 3E 0D 0A 20 20 20 3C 2F 73 6F 61 70 65 6E 76 3A 42 6F 64 79 3E 0D 0A 3C 2F 73 6F 61 70 65 6E 76 3A 45
>    6E 76 65 6C 6F 70 65 3E 73 72 01 00 17 6A 61 76 61 2E 75 74 69 6C 2E 4C 69 6E 6B 65 64 48 61 73 68 4D 61 70 78 72 01 00 11 6A 61 76 61 2E 75 74 69 6C 2E 48 61 73 68 4D 6
>   1 70 78 70 3F 40 00 00 00 00 00 0C 77 08 00 00 00 10 00 00 00 0B 74 00 0B 4A 4D 53 50 72 69 6F 72 69 74 79 73 72 01 00 11 6A 61 76 61 2E 6C 61 6E 67 2E 49 6E 74 65 67 65
>   72 78 72 01 00 10 6A 61 76 61 2E 6C 61 6E 67 2E 4E 75 6D 62 65 72 78 70 00 00 00 00 74 00 0E 4A 4D 53 44 65 73 74 69 6E 61 74 69 6F 6E 73 72 00 00 29 6F 72 67 2E 61 70 61
>    63 68 65 2E 61 63 74 69 76 65 6D 71 2E 63 6F 6D 6D 61 6E 64 2E 41 63 74 69 76 65 4D 51 51 75 65 75 65 CA 14 C8 99 F4 3B 9F 0F 0C 00 00 78 72 00 00 2F 6F 72 67 2E 61 70 6
>   1 63 68 65 2E 61 63 74 69 76 65 6D 71 2E 63 6F 6D 6D 61 6E 64 2E 41 63 74 69 76 65 4D 51 44 65 73 74 69 6E 61 74 69 6F 6E CA 14 C8 99 F4 3B 9F 0F 0C 00 00 78 72 00 00 29
>   6F 72 67 2E 61 70 61 63 68 65 2E 61 63 74 69 76 65 6D 71 2E 6A 6E 64 69 2E 4A 4E 44 49 42 61 73 65 53 74 6F 72 61 62 6C 65 54 EE B2 4F 8E 12 4D E9 0C 00 00 78 70 77 0B 00
>    09 51 2E 56 53 52 53 2E 49 4E 70 78 74 00 08 70 73 2D 4D 73 67 49 64 74 00 2D 75 72 6E 3A 75 75 69 64 3A 36 31 32 30 35 61 35 34 2D 34 39 31 63 2D 64 35 36 39 2D 65 31 3
>   0 30 2D 30 30 30 30 30 61 32 39 33 38 34 37 74 00 0C 4A 4D 53 54 69 6D 65 73 74 61 6D 70 73 72 01 00 0E 6A 61 76 61 2E 6C 61 6E 67 2E 4C 6F 6E 67 78 71 00 7E 00 0E 00 00
>   01 49 AE 36 96 56 74 00 10 4A 4D 53 43 6F 72 72 65 6C 61 74 69 6F 6E 49 44 74 00 00 74 00 0C 62 72 65 61 64 63 72 75 6D 62 49 64 74 00 29 49 44 3A 52 37 30 36 57 57 38 50
>    2D 35 36 34 36 32 2D 31 34 31 35 39 36 35 37 34 30 32 30 35 2D 31 3A 32 3A 31 3A 31 3A 35 74 00 0E 4A 4D 53 52 65 64 65 6C 69 76 65 72 65 64 73 72 01 00 11 6A 61 76 61 2
>   E 6C 61 6E 67 2E 42 6F 6F 6C 65 61 6E 78 70 00 74 00 0C 4A 4D 53 4D 65 73 73 61 67 65 49 44 71 00 7E 00 1D 74 00 0F 4A 4D 53 44 65 6C 69 76 65 72 79 4D 6F 64 65 73 71 00
>   7E 00 0D 00 00 00 01 74 00 0D 4A 4D 53 45 78 70 69 72 61 74 69 6F 6E 73 71 00 7E 00 18 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 74 00 07 4A 4D 53 54 79 70 65 74 00 00 78 00 70 71 00 7E 00
>    20 70 73 71 00 7E 00 09 3F 40 00 00 00 00 00 0C 77 08 00 00 00 10 00 00 00 03 74 00 0F 43 61 6D 65 6C 54 6F 45 6E 64 70 6F 69 6E 74 74 00 3D 6D 69 6E 61 32 3A 2F 2F 74 6
>   3 70 3A 2F 2F 6C 6F 63 61 6C 68 6F 73 74 3A 39 39 38 31 3F 73 79 6E 63 3D 66 61 6C 73 65 26 74 72 61 6E 73 66 65 72 45 78 63 68 61 6E 67 65 3D 74 72 75 65 74 00 15 43 61
>   6D 65 6C 43 72 65 61 74 65 64 54 69 6D 65 73 74 61 6D 70 73 72 01 00 0E 6A 61 76 61 2E 75 74 69 6C 2E 44 61 74 65 78 70 77 08 00 00 01 49 AE 36 96 58 78 74 00 18 43 61 6D
>    65 6C 45 78 74 65 72 6E 61 6C 52 65 64 65 6C 69 76 65 72 65 64 71 00 7E 00 20 78 00)
>           at org.apache.camel.component.mina2.Mina2Consumer$ReceiveHandler.exceptionCaught(Mina2Consumer.java:317)[195:org.apache.camel.camel-mina2:2.13.2]
>           at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain$TailFilter.exceptionCaught(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:672)[33:org.apache.mina.core:2.0.7]
>           at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.callNextExceptionCaught(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:461)[33:org.apache.mina.core:2.0.7]
>           at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.access$1100(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:47)[33:org.apache.mina.core:2.0.7]
>           at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain$EntryImpl$1.exceptionCaught(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:760)[33:org.apache.mina.core:2.0.7]
>           at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.IoFilterEvent.fire(IoFilterEvent.java:93)[33:org.apache.mina.core:2.0.7]
>           at org.apache.mina.core.session.IoEvent.run(IoEvent.java:63)[33:org.apache.mina.core:2.0.7]
>           at org.apache.mina.filter.executor.OrderedThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(OrderedThreadPoolExecutor.java:769)[33:org.apache.mina.core:2.0.7]
>           at org.apache.mina.filter.executor.OrderedThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTasks(OrderedThreadPoolExecutor.java:761)[33:org.apache.mina.core:2.0.7]
>           at org.apache.mina.filter.executor.OrderedThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(OrderedThreadPoolExecutor.java:703)[33:org.apache.mina.core:2.0.7]
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)[:1.7.0_67]
>   Caused by: org.apache.mina.filter.codec.ProtocolDecoderException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultExchangeHolder (Hexdump: 79 3E 0D 0A 20 2
>   0 20 3C 2F 73 6F 61 70 65 6E 76 3A 48 65 61 64 65 72 3E 0D 0A 20 20 20 3C 73 6F 61 70 65 6E 76 3A 42 6F 64 79 20 77 73 75 3A 49 64 3D 22 63 34 34 62 31 65 66 38 2D 31 63
>   35 30 2D 34 62 38 65 2D 38 31 33 37 2D 38 30 62 35 38 30 35 33 61 37 33 30 22 20 78 6D 6C 6E 73 3A 77 73 75 3D 22 68 74 74 70 3A 2F 2F 64 6F 63 73 2E 6F 61 73 69 73 2D 6F
>    70 65 6E 2E 6F 72 67 2F 77 73 73 2F 32 30 30 34 2F 30 31 2F 6F 61 73 69 73 2D 32 30 30 34 30 31 2D 77 73 73 2D 77 73 73 65 63 75 72 69 74 79 2D 75 74 69 6C 69 74 79 2D 3
>   1 2E 30 2E 78 73 64 22 3E 0D 0A 20 20 20 20 20 20 3C 6E 30 3A 47 65 74 56 65 68 69 63 6C 65 53 70 65 63 69 66 69 63 61 74 69 6F 6E 42 79 56 49 4E 20 78 6D 6C 6E 73 3A 6E
>   30 3D 22 68 74 74 70 3A 2F 2F 78 6D 6C 64 65 66 73 2E 76 6F 6C 6B 73 77 61 67 65 6E 61 67 2E 63 6F 6D 2F 43 53 50 2F 55 73 65 64 43 61 72 73 2F 56 65 68 69 63 6C 65 53 70
>    65 63 69 66 69 63 61 74 69 6F 6E 52 65 63 6F 76 65 72 79 53 65 72 76 69 63 65 2F 56 31 22 20 78 6D 6C 6E 73 3A 70 72 78 3D 22 75 72 6E 3A 73 61 70 2E 63 6F 6D 3A 70 72 6
>   F 78 79 3A 46 35 50 3A 2F 31 53 41 49 2F 54 41 53 34 32 41 35 33 42 41 38 35 32 45 30 30 30 32 32 36 37 43 35 3A 37 30 31 3A 32 30 31 33 2F 30 35 2F 32 34 22 20 78 6D 6C
>   6E 73 3A 6E 31 3D 22 68 74 74 70 3A 2F 2F 78 6D 6C 64 65 66 73 2E 76 6F 6C 6B 73 77 61 67 65 6E 61 67 2E 63 6F 6D 2F 44 44 2F 56 65 68 69 63 6C 65 2F 52 65 66 2F 56 31 22
>    20 78 6D 6C 6E 73 3A 73 6F 61 70 2D 65 6E 76 3D 22 68 74 74 70 3A 2F 2F 73 63 68 65 6D 61 73 2E 78 6D 6C 73 6F 61 70 2E 6F 72 67 2F 73 6F 61 70 2F 65 6E 76 65 6C 6F 70 6
>   5 2F 22 3E 0D 0A 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 3C 6E 31 3A 56 65 68 69 63 6C 65 52 65 66 3E 0D 0A 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 3C 6E 31 3A 56 49 4E 3E 57 41 55 5A 5A
>   5A 38 54 37 43 41 30 34 31 35 35 38 3C 2F 6E 31 3A 56 49 4E 3E 0D 0A 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 3C 2F 6E 31 3A 56 65 68 69 63 6C 65 52 65 66 3E 0D 0A 20 20 20 20 20 20 20
>    20 20 3C 6E 30 3A 4C 61 6E 67 75 61 67 65 3E 64 65 3C 2F 6E 30 3A 4C 61 6E 67 75 61 67 65 3E 0D 0A 20 20 20 20 20 20 3C 2F 6E 30 3A 47 65 74 56 65 68 69 63 6C 65 53 70 6
>   5 63 69 66 69 63 61 74 69 6F 6E 42 79 56 49 4E 3E 0D 0A 20 20 20 3C 2F 73 6F 61 70 65 6E 76 3A 42 6F 64 79 3E 0D 0A 3C 2F 73 6F 61 70 65 6E 76 3A 45 6E 76 65 6C 6F 70 65
>   3E 73 72 01 00 17 6A 61 76 61 2E 75 74 69 6C 2E 4C 69 6E 6B 65 64 48 61 73 68 4D 61 70 78 72 01 00 11 6A 61 76 61 2E 75 74 69 6C 2E 48 61 73 68 4D 61 70 78 70 3F 40 00 00
>    00 00 00 0C 77 08 00 00 00 10 00 00 00 0B 74 00 0B 4A 4D 53 50 72 69 6F 72 69 74 79 73 72 01 00 11 6A 61 76 61 2E 6C 61 6E 67 2E 49 6E 74 65 67 65 72 78 72 01 00 10 6A 6
>   1 76 61 2E 6C 61 6E 67 2E 4E 75 6D 62 65 72 78 70 00 00 00 00 74 00 0E 4A 4D 53 44 65 73 74 69 6E 61 74 69 6F 6E 73 72 00 00 29 6F 72 67 2E 61 70 61 63 68 65 2E 61 63 74
>   69 76 65 6D 71 2E 63 6F 6D 6D 61 6E 64 2E 41 63 74 69 76 65 4D 51 51 75 65 75 65 CA 14 C8 99 F4 3B 9F 0F 0C 00 00 78 72 00 00 2F 6F 72 67 2E 61 70 61 63 68 65 2E 61 63 74
>    69 76 65 6D 71 2E 63 6F 6D 6D 61 6E 64 2E 41 63 74 69 76 65 4D 51 44 65 73 74 69 6E 61 74 69 6F 6E CA 14 C8 99 F4 3B 9F 0F 0C 00 00 78 72 00 00 29 6F 72 67 2E 61 70 61 6
>   3 68 65 2E 61 63 74 69 76 65 6D 71 2E 6A 6E 64 69 2E 4A 4E 44 49 42 61 73 65 53 74 6F 72 61 62 6C 65 54 EE B2 4F 8E 12 4D E9 0C 00 00 78 70 77 0B 00 09 51 2E 56 53 52 53
>   2E 49 4E 70 78 74 00 08 70 73 2D 4D 73 67 49 64 74 00 2D 75 72 6E 3A 75 75 69 64 3A 36 31 32 30 35 61 35 34 2D 34 39 31 63 2D 64 35 36 39 2D 65 31 30 30 2D 30 30 30 30 30
>    61 32 39 33 38 34 37 74 00 0C 4A 4D 53 54 69 6D 65 73 74 61 6D 70 73 72 01 00 0E 6A 61 76 61 2E 6C 61 6E 67 2E 4C 6F 6E 67 78 71 00 7E 00 0E 00 00 01 49 AE 36 96 56 74 0
>   0 10 4A 4D 53 43 6F 72 72 65 6C 61 74 69 6F 6E 49 44 74 00 00 74 00 0C 62 72 65 61 64 63 72 75 6D 62 49 64 74 00 29 49 44 3A 52 37 30 36 57 57 38 50 2D 35 36 34 36 32 2D
>   31 34 31 35 39 36 35 37 34 30 32 30 35 2D 31 3A 32 3A 31 3A 31 3A 35 74 00 0E 4A 4D 53 52 65 64 65 6C 69 76 65 72 65 64 73 72 01 00 11 6A 61 76 61 2E 6C 61 6E 67 2E 42 6F
>    6F 6C 65 61 6E 78 70 00 74 00 0C 4A 4D 53 4D 65 73 73 61 67 65 49 44 71 00 7E 00 1D 74 00 0F 4A 4D 53 44 65 6C 69 76 65 72 79 4D 6F 64 65 73 71 00 7E 00 0D 00 00 00 01 7
>   4 00 0D 4A 4D 53 45 78 70 69 72 61 74 69 6F 6E 73 71 00 7E 00 18 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 74 00 07 4A 4D 53 54 79 70 65 74 00 00 78 00 70 71 00 7E 00 20 70 73 71 00 7E 00
>   09 3F 40 00 00 00 00 00 0C 77 08 00 00 00 10 00 00 00 03 74 00 0F 43 61 6D 65 6C 54 6F 45 6E 64 70 6F 69 6E 74 74 00 3D 6D 69 6E 61 32 3A 2F 2F 74 63 70 3A 2F 2F 6C 6F 63
>    61 6C 68 6F 73 74 3A 39 39 38 31 3F 73 79 6E 63 3D 66 61 6C 73 65 26 74 72 61 6E 73 66 65 72 45 78 63 68 61 6E 67 65 3D 74 72 75 65 74 00 15 43 61 6D 65 6C 43 72 65 61 7
>   4 65 64 54 69 6D 65 73 74 61 6D 70 73 72 01 00 0E 6A 61 76 61 2E 75 74 69 6C 2E 44 61 74 65 78 70 77 08 00 00 01 49 AE 36 96 58 78 74 00 18 43 61 6D 65 6C 45 78 74 65 72
>   6E 61 6C 52 65 64 65 6C 69 76 65 72 65 64 71 00 7E 00 20 78 00)
>           at org.apache.mina.filter.codec.ProtocolCodecFilter.messageReceived(ProtocolCodecFilter.java:242)[33:org.apache.mina.core:2.0.7]
>           at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.callNextMessageReceived(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:417)[33:org.apache.mina.core:2.0.7]
>           at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.access$1200(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:47)[33:org.apache.mina.core:2.0.7]
>           at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain$EntryImpl$1.messageReceived(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:765)[33:org.apache.mina.core:2.0.7]
>           at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.IoFilterAdapter.messageReceived(IoFilterAdapter.java:109)[33:org.apache.mina.core:2.0.7]
>           at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.callNextMessageReceived(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:417)[33:org.apache.mina.core:2.0.7]
>           at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.fireMessageReceived(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:410)[33:org.apache.mina.core:2.0.7]
>           at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoProcessor.read(AbstractPollingIoProcessor.java:710)[33:org.apache.mina.core:2.0.7]
>           at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoProcessor.process(AbstractPollingIoProcessor.java:664)[33:org.apache.mina.core:2.0.7]
>           at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoProcessor.process(AbstractPollingIoProcessor.java:653)[33:org.apache.mina.core:2.0.7]
>           at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoProcessor.access$600(AbstractPollingIoProcessor.java:67)[33:org.apache.mina.core:2.0.7]
>           at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoProcessor$Processor.run(AbstractPollingIoProcessor.java:1124)[33:org.apache.mina.core:2.0.7]
>           at org.apache.mina.util.NamePreservingRunnable.run(NamePreservingRunnable.java:64)[33:org.apache.mina.core:2.0.7]
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)[:1.7.0_67]
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)[:1.7.0_67]
>           ... 1 more
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultExchangeHolder
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)[:1.7.0_67]
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)[:1.7.0_67]
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)[:1.7.0_67]
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)[:1.7.0_67]
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)[:1.7.0_67]
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)[:1.7.0_67]
>           at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.doImplicitBootDelegation(BundleWiringImpl.java:1763)[org.apache.felix.framework-4.4.1.jar:]
>           at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.searchDynamicImports(BundleWiringImpl.java:1698)[org.apache.felix.framework-4.4.1.jar:]
>           at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.findClassOrResourceByDelegation(BundleWiringImpl.java:1534)[org.apache.felix.framework-4.4.1.jar:]
>           at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.access$400(BundleWiringImpl.java:77)[org.apache.felix.framework-4.4.1.jar:]
>           at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.loadClass(BundleWiringImpl.java:1993)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)[:1.7.0_67]
>           at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)[:1.7.0_67]
>           at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:270)[:1.7.0_67]
>           at java.io.ObjectInputStream.resolveClass(ObjectInputStream.java:625)[:1.7.0_67]
>           at org.apache.mina.core.buffer.AbstractIoBuffer$3.resolveClass(AbstractIoBuffer.java:2180)[33:org.apache.mina.core:2.0.7]
>           at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1612)[:1.7.0_67]
>           at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1517)[:1.7.0_67]
>           at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1771)[:1.7.0_67]
>           at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)[:1.7.0_67]
>           at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:370)[:1.7.0_67]
>           at org.apache.mina.core.buffer.AbstractIoBuffer.getObject(AbstractIoBuffer.java:2184)[33:org.apache.mina.core:2.0.7]
>           at org.apache.mina.filter.codec.serialization.ObjectSerializationDecoder.doDecode(ObjectSerializationDecoder.java:90)[33:org.apache.mina.core:2.0.7]
>           at org.apache.mina.filter.codec.CumulativeProtocolDecoder.decode(CumulativeProtocolDecoder.java:176)[33:org.apache.mina.core:2.0.7]
>           at org.apache.mina.filter.codec.ProtocolCodecFilter.messageReceived(ProtocolCodecFilter.java:232)[33:org.apache.mina.core:2.0.7]
>           ... 15 more
>   2014-11-14 13:16:21,864 | WARN  | ssionScavenger-1 | teInvalidatingHashSessionManager | ?                                   ? | 72 - org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-jetty - 3.1
>   .2 | Timing out for 1 session(s) with id 4ne1k7kkiu7m191fy7qrkgc7v

karaf@root>

So how can I fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to update the OSGi meta data for importing package of org.apache.camel.impl.

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "update the OSGI meta data"? Could you give an example? Thank you?